# django file upload in 2 steps

Tags: django

I want to upload a file in 2 steps. 
First I want to upload it and show the errors and on the second step I 
want actually to save the file data in the database. 
So I made a simple form and my problem is how to pass the same file to 
the form on the second step? 
I mean how to insert request.FILES data in the same form again. Or 
maybe there is a better way? 
Thanks, 
Arshavski Alexander.

Comment: maybe you could pass it around within session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,

Using django's inbuilt File field, you don't store the files in the database, but in the filesystem. You only store the metadata in the database.

Next,

If you want to validate a file input, you can use the standard form validation, where you define the the `clean_file_field_name` and raise the `forms.ValidationError` django automatically does the "showing of the page until proper input is provided" for you.

That is the right way of doing it.